# ASP.NET MVC and friendly URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, url-rewriting, seo, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to learn a bit more about creating friendly URLs, particularly in relation to something like an e-commerce site. If you take a look at this site as an example: http://www.wiggle.co.uk/

It basically lets you refine your search based on the categories. So if I go to http://www.wiggle.co.uk/mens/road-time-trial-bikes/ it will list all men's road bikes, if I then go to http://www.wiggle.co.uk/road-time-trial-bikes/ it will list men's and women's bikes, and if I go to http://www.wiggle.co.uk/bianchi-sempre-105/ it will display a particular bike.

I'm not really sure what the routing would look like for something like this, as you could have many filters in the URL. I'm also not sure how how it's able to distinguish between what's a filter and what's a product.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you are fairly close but would break out the second and third as it would be a little ambiguous for the one Action to interpret the two parameters.  I'd suggest the following:

http://www.wiggle.co.uk/road-time-trial-bikes/

http://www.wiggle.co.uk/**bikes**/bianchi-sempre-105/

Thus /bikes/ could be routed clearly to a different controller and action.  You would need to create a specific rule for the root or you could add a specific controller, say bike-types, to the first url

http://www.wiggle.co.uk/**bike-types**/road-time-trial-bikes/

The specifics on routing are well documented but a good place to start might be with writing some tests to help you understand what works and give you more confidence with making changes to your routes.  It is very easy to create clashing routes and tests help prevent this.
http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper#Routes

Comment: My examples are from an actual site though, so they've obviously managed to do it like that somehow. :) I suppose when viewing an actual product, you could include the ID in the route, which would avoid the ambiguity. But I'm still not sure how you would define the routing for the filters. Thanks for the testing link too.

Comment: @Tom is it all new to you?  where are you having trouble?  ID would not necessarily remove ambiguity (both categories and types might have IDs).  That said you could create urls like wiggle has but you would want to understand what you are doing and to repeat the mantra, write your tests and build your own understanding through writing more and more tests.  I'll include some more material in answer based on what you are looking for.

Comment: Not new, I just haven't done anything beyond your typical routes before. It would remove the ambiguity, as you're not likely to have a filter that's just a number, so I could create a constraint that for that. I'm just not sure how to define a route that could include either multiple filters or just one filter, e.g. /bikes/mens/road-bikes or just /bikes/mens. Is it as simple as just defining a catch-all?

Comment: @Tom the choices are almost unbounded.  However, for clarity it's probably not bad to be a little specific, after all it would read better if you had some indication in url if it was a bike or bike type you were calling.  Thus I'd stick to have more specific controllers and urls rather than one catch all as that opens it up to not just routing ambiguity but audience understanding the urls.  Not an expert but would say it's more RESTful to have slightly more structured urls.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll look a bit more in to it. I did just find this which seems to explain it quite well: http://erraticdev.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html

Comment: @Tom it's definitely worth spending some time to understand well or you'll end up in a mess.  again I'd stress that this is a place where tests are invaluable.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17126/discussion-between-dove-and-tom)